# @metamask/eth-sig-util" buffer isn't defined?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to encrypt some data using MetaMask's public key for encryption (https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#unrestricted-methods).
However, on page load I'm getting the error `Buffer is not defined`:

[image]

It seems to only happen when I've imported the  `'@metamask/eth-sig-util'` script and try to encrypt data:

```
import ethUtil from 'ethereumjs-util'
import sigUtil from '@metamask/eth-sig-util'

const encryptedData = ethUtil.bufferToHex(
  Buffer.from(
    JSON.stringify(
      sigUtil.encrypt({
        publicKey: publicKey,
        data: 'hello world data',
        version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305',
      })
    ),
    'utf8'
  )
)
```

I've tried adding in `import { Buffer } from 'buffer/'`, but this doesn't seem to help.

If I omit  `import sigUtil from '@metamask/eth-sig-util'` or

```
const encryptedData = ethUtil.bufferToHex(
  Buffer.from(
    JSON.stringify(
      sigUtil.encrypt({
        publicKey: publicKey,
        data: 'hello world data',
        version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305',
      })
    ),
    'utf8'
  )
)
```

The error goes away. I've also tried switching to using `eth-sig-util@2.5.3` instead of the newer `@metamask/eth-sig-util`, but the error still persists.

Since I've tried all of the above including using a different package version, I'm starting to wonder if this isn't a bug within the `@metamask/eth-sig-util` library. What is causing this issue? I'm using Vite to build my project and I've tested on both Chrome and FireFox, but the error still persists. What should I check?

Comment: Same issue. I think eth-sig-util was made to run in the backend, because Buffer is a Nodejs structure. It surprises me how little attention this issue has received.

Comment: Verification should happen in the backend so I think there's little demand for frontend `eth-sig-util`.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run `eth-sig-util` in the frontend. `eth-sig-util` depends on a Nodejs structure called `Buffer`. Try using Metamask's `ethereum` API https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html